# Dissolving polygons with common attribute within certain proximity to each other using QGIS?

Tags: qgis, dissolve

I have a land parcel with a lot of polygons with the same attribute (owners). I would like to dissolve all the polygons with the same owners but only if the polygons are within 100m of each other. How would I go about this on a large scale (ie >10000 polygons)?

Using QGIS 1.8

The purpose is to group together large properties (Farms) into their actual operating unit rather than based on property title.

Comment: What is the goal with this operation? It seems like a half-measure. If you dissolve everything on owner, you get one shape/record per owner. But if only do the ones within 100m of each other (but not *only* adjacent), you have fewer but still multiple shapes/records per owner with a loss of their individual attributes. As far as actually doing it, I can't think of any way that isn't going to involve some type of script or model. I suppose it might be possible with a single distance matrix (if QGIS can do all and not just nearest) to figure out which ones need to be dissolved.

Comment: @ChrisW - I believe you are right in using the **Distance Matrix**, this allows _each_ feature to have their distance calculated with _every_ other feature (select the owner field as the unique ID). Using the output file, you can then select all features within 100m using `HubDist <= 100`, invert this selection and delete the unwanted features. Then do a **dissolve** in terms of the owner. Should give you a similar result you were looking for. @ChrisW, you should post an answer to this question.

Comment: @Joseph I'll leave this one to you as you're more familiar with the actual tool. I take it that using owner as a uniqueID it will only compare polys with the same owner to each other, but it will do so for the entire dataset? You would have to add another step to incorporate/replace the dissolved geometries/records into the original data. If software allows you might be able to select parcels in the original based on whether they are in the (separate) 'dissolve target' set, then dissolve on owner (ie, a nested query). I know it's doable in Arc as long as your data is in a specific format.

Comment: That purpose makes sense, although in my experience fields of a given 'farm' operator can be separated by miles, or leased rather than owned. Practices probably vary by region I suppose.

Comment: @ChrisW - Urghh, ignore my comment above. The **Distance Matrix** tool only works for points, not polygons (guess I wasn't fully awake when I added that!). I suppose you could convert the polygons to centroid points and then follow on but depends on the size and shape of the polygon. There is a **Join attributes table**  tool which you can use to 'import' the original data for each owner.